# RegEx with Word 2013. Match string AFTER known word to End of Line or <table>

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I'm using the Find and Replace feature in a large word document I have. I need to find the word **REMARKS:** (all bold and upppercase).

> REMARKS: THIS IS SOME IMPORTANT DATA

At then end of that line or after a line break is a TABLE if that can help in the reqex.

Using find / replace with use Wildcards Checked and this expression:

> <(REMARKS:*[A-Z])

I've found the word and the first Char after the space:

**REMARKS: T**

*What can I add to make it stop at the end of the line? There is always a table the proceeds this "REMARK:" text*

For example in javascript: /.*REMARKS:\s*([A-Z,0-9]).+/g will find it, but is not acceptable in Word's find and replace....

I've also found that using:

> <(REMARKS:*[A-Z]^l) or <(REMARKS:*[A-Z]^13) will get me closer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Match string AFTER known word to End of Line

Use the following regular expression:

```
<(REMARKS:[0-9A-Z ]@[^13^|])
```

Notes:

- `<` matches "The beginning of a word"
- `[0-9A-Z ]` matches any number, uppercase letter, or space
- `@` matches "One or more occurrences of the previous character or expression"
- `[^13^|]` matches a paragraph marker or a manual line break.

---

#### Further Reading

- [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm)
- [Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f)